# Telerik Asp.Net MVC ComboBox placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, combobox, telerik

I am having a small problem with a Terlerik ComboBox using Asp.Net MVC.

```
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
        .Name("Studio") //The name of the DropDownList is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
        .Placeholder("-- Studio --")
        .DataTextField("Name") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the DropDownList as a text.
        .DataValueField("Id") //Specify which property of the Product to be used by the DropDownList as a value.
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "target" })
        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
            read.Action("GetStandorte", "Api"); //Set the Action and Controller names.
          });
        })
        .Enable(true)
        .AutoBind(false)
    )
```

The ComboBox is not accepting the placeholder. It is always "0". Why is that? What do I have to change in order to display the placeholder?

Comment: try providing the placeholder after kendo declaration as $("#Studio").data("kendoComboBox").input.attr("placeholder", "-- Studio --");

Comment: That doesn't work for me